# How to extract validation data from training data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have following statement

```
self.__Dir_Data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(self.__Dir_Path ,validation_split = 0.1 ,subset="training", seed = 1,  labels='inferred', label_mode='int' ,batch_size=32 ,image_size=(124, 124))
```

I would like to extract from following Dir Data, separate Validation Data

Greetings
DA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the call to image_dataset_from_directory,  set subset='training for the train dataset and set it to 'validation' for the validation set as shown below

```
train_data=tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(self.__Dir_Path ,validation_split = 0.1 ,subset="training", seed = 1,  labels='inferred', label_mode='int' ,batch_size=32 ,image_size=(124, 124))

validation_data=tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(self.__Dir_Path ,validation_split = 0.1 ,subset="validation", seed = 1,  labels='inferred', label_mode='int' ,batch_size=32 ,image_size=(124, 124))
```

Comment: Thanks and how to use this function to load test images?

Comment: set directory to path to test directory, set validation_split to None and subset=None.

Comment: Okay, hmm one thing makes me curious, how to extract one single image for prediction purposes?